# Find element in Set and add to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, set

For reference: 
Class Product http://pastebin.com/LUWVzkNj
Class Shop http://pastebin.com/XLRwBfrQ
Class Cart http://pastebin.com/jqZcH4HK

I have a Shop (Set) with products (itemNumber, Price), and now I would like to search for a product using the itemNumber and add this product to a Cart (ArrayList). For this I have to create a method called find product. Things that I have tried but could not complete:

1. Using a for-loop trying to find the product and adding it to the cart (not sure if == or equals is correct):

   ```
   public void findProduct(int ItemNumber){
   for (Product item : item )
   {if (item.getItemNumber() == itemNumber)
   {add();}
   ```
2. Iterate through the set to find the product

   ```
   public void findProduct(int itemNumber)
   {for(Iterator<Product> it = products.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
   {Product p = it.next(); 
   if (p.equals(new Product()))
   //add this product}}
   ```
3. Check if set contains the itemNumber given and then add this product

   ```
   public void findProduct(int itemNumber)
   {if (products.contains(itemNumber))
   {//add this product; }}
   ```

I tried to google if you can add elements from a Set to an ArrayList or if you could find a specific element in a set list but couldn't find anything or nothing that was specific enough to help me out. So I am wondering if any of these would actually work once I manage to complete them?

Comment: maybe the merhod `findProduct` should return something (other than void) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach is simple and valid at the same time, but you need a few more control:

```
public void findProduct(int ItemNumber){
   for (Product item : item ) {
      if (item.getItemNumber() == itemNumber){
         cart.add (item)
         break; //to leave the loop once it's found
   }
```

cart is your arrayList

Answer (score 1):

Your first version is possible. But your for-each- loop will not work:

```
public void findProduct(int itemNumber){
   for (Product item : shop) {
      if (item.getItemNumber() == itemNumber){
         cart.add(item)
         break;
   }
```

`cart` is your list and `shop`is your set.